# cannot update pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to update a Pandas dataframe.
Please find my code below:

```
#if ((__name__) == ('__main__')):
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name','value'])
print('Starting traffic counters')
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=TrafficCountersData.fetchTrafficCounters, daemon=True)
thread1.start()

while True:
    getCounterValue = TrafficCountersData.getcounter()
    #print(f'Get Call Output: {TrafficCountersData.getcounter()}')
    dataVolPerInterface.append(getCounterValue['value'])
    filt = (df['name'] == ('VENET_ONT001_LAN1'))
    print(filt)
    #df.loc[filt]
    if(filt):
        print("List of values::", dataVolPerInterface)
        #df.loc[filt,['name','value']] = [getCounterValue['name'], np.array(dataVolPerInterface, dtype=object)]
        df.at[filt] = [getCounterValue['name'], np.array(dataVolPerInterface, dtype=object)]
        #df.at[filt,'value'] = 6576
    else:
        df.loc[len(df.index)] = [getCounterValue['name'], np.array(dataVolPerInterface, dtype=object)]
    print(df)
    time.sleep(TrafficCountersData.ci + 1)
```

I am getting below error. I don't want to use any of the below option among Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). The reason is if i am using any of the option, I am not able to update the dataframe. It's giving an error.

[image]

Comment: From the print statement it seems that `filt` is strangely not a Series with bool values - is that correct?

Comment: a statement like filt = (df['name'] == ('VENET_ONT001_LAN1')) does not set filt to true or false, it sets filt to a Series, which is sort of like a long list containing a true/false values one for every row of df, depending on whether the statement was true for the row. Therefore if you write if(filt) it's sort of like writing if([True,False,True,True]), doesn't make a lot of sense. What are you trying to do with the if statement?

Comment: Thanks All. I have added the requirement below. Please check.

Comment: I cannot see any added requirements. Is the output in the picture really from that code? ```print(filt)``` should not have given the ```{'metric': ... )``` but rather ```{true, false, ... )```. Have you tried the solution below? What about that part: "The reason is if i am using any of the option, I am not able to update the dataframe. It's giving an error." What is the error? Which option did you use and why?

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` condition does (rightfully) not know how to handle a Series. `if(filt)` could return a lot of things and pandas does not know what you expect it to do: e.g. `true` if it exists, `true` if it has at least one non-nan entry, ...

I guess what you want is to execute the code if the series `filt` exists, therefore if it is not empty. Try
`if(~filt.empty):`